# python print to execute string literal as part of code

Tags: python

I am using python make some of the SQL queries I have to for my JDBC connections more modular and would like to execute parts of my string literals with print statements.

```
fh = open("data.txt","w")
print("42 is the answer, but what is the question?", file=fh)
fh.close()
```

I know I can use this to write to text but I would like to save the outputs of my print in a local variable to call later in other statements.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you for the edit Wondercricket.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = "42 is the answer, but what is the question?"
with open("data.txt","w") as fh:
    fh.write(output)
```

Comment: @Flufylobster I don't understand what you mean. Make your question clear.